# Issue with text filling, CSS Animation

Tags: html, css

This is a CSS and HTML animation, simple text filling.
For some reason the text jumps when there is a space or if I add a dash?

Below you can see the output:
[image]

I've added the code below!

```css
.comingsoon-loading {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.comingsoon-loading h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20vh;
  color:  #ffcc00;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.comingsoon-loading h1::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0px black;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: animate 6s linear infinite;
}

/* animation to fill text */

@keyframes animate
{
  0%,10%,100%
  {
    width: 0;
  }
  50%,70%
  {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="comingsoon-loading">
      <h1 data-text="COMING-SOON">COMING-SOON</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your html so we can see it in action

Comment: You need to add html code as well so that we can understand the whole scenario

Comment: just added the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem lies in the way you handle text in your animation.

You are animating a string of text appearing slowly but don't account for any of the inherit string properties such as **line breaking**.
During your animation, the first word: "COMING", appears normally as the width increases, but once the hyphen appears, HTML thinks you have inserted a word **break point** and tries to break "SOON" to a new line.

This can be solved by adding `white-space: nowrap;` to your `::before` section, to prevent it from breaking as the animation plays out.

**HTML**

```
<div class="comingsoon-loading">
  <h1 data-text="COMING-SOON">COMING-SOON</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.comingsoon-loading {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.comingsoon-loading h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20vh;
  color: #ffcc00;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.comingsoon-loading h1::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0px black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* animation to fill text */

@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  10%,
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50%,
  70% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very very much, something so simple haha thanks very much appreciate!